# global key/unique attribute in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I am trying those days to find a way to create a global attribute that will be used by all the elements in the schema and will serve as a key/unique attribute to them a well.
look a the next example:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.NameSpace/Family" xmlns:tns="http://www.NameSpace/Family">
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:complexType name="parentType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Child" type="tns:childType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>  
  <xs:attribute ref="tns:id" use="required"/>  
</xs:complexType>  
<xs:complexType name="childType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>  
  <xs:attribute ref="tns:id" use="required"/>  
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Family">  
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Parent" type="tns:parentType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

now lets say for example, I create 1 parent with 2 kids, I want do define a key/unique on the id attribute so that **all the elements id's (parents an childs) will be different from each other**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `id` as having type `xsd:ID` like this:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
```

Then you reference the declared attribute (like you already do):

```
<xs:complexType name="parentType">
...
  <xs:attribute ref="tns:id" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

You could also just declare the `id` attribute on the types or elements directly.

The `xs:ID` type imposes `ID` semantics globally on all `ID`-declared attributes in a document.

Answer (score 0):

To create a key, use the `<xs:key>` element. In your case, you want to establish a key across a set of elements that is within the `<Family>` element. Therefore, your key would be within the `<xs:element>` tag that defines `Family`.

```
<xs:element name="Family">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Parent" type="tns:parentType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- SOMETHING LIKE THIS WILL DO -->
  <xs:key name="id">
    <xs:selector xpath="tns:Parent|tns:Parent/tns:Child" />
    <xs:field xpath="@tns:id" />
  </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

You could also use `<xs:unique>` instead of `<xs:key>`. The only difference between the two is that `<xs:unique>` allows the field to be optional. In your case, where your `id` attribute is required by definition of the schema, there would be no difference using either `<xs:unique>` or `<xs:key>`.

Comment: Also please note that I edited your post to fix 5 typos in the XSD.